# Flutter/Dart/Firebase - Reduce unnecessary data loading

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I tried searching my specific problem but I could not find any suitable solution. 
I would like to thank everybody in advance for your help.

I am currently developing an iOS app. 
The App represents a user profile which can be updated by the user. 
Everything from the authentication, registration and the possibility to update your user data works fine with the help of Firebase. Now I would like to optimize some code.
So the application has 2 Screens, HomeScreen and EditScreen. 
(Besides the Screens needed for registration and login).

To keep my question short:
How can I reduce the amount of data which is loaded from firebase?

Example:
1. User is on the HomeScreen, to build the view his image loads from Firebase Storage
2. He wants to edit his Image and therefore switches to the Editscreen, where his image will be loaded again
3. After changing his image, the new image will be uploaded to Firebase Storage and he can see his new image on the Editscreen
4. If he now switches back to the HomeScreen his new image will be loaded again from Firebase

Is there a good way to reduce the amount of loading? 
Like caching the image between step 1 and 2? 
As there is always a little delay in displaying his image.

Thanks! 
Sadly I am not allowed to share any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the [flutter_advanced_networkimage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage) package. It will cache your photo upon load. For everything else, you should just move your `profile` object (or whatever it is that calls for the firebase user's information) above those routes and pass it down through your widget tree through arguments or state management.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I
 lack in knowledge about the various ways of state management. So I will take a dive into it and then work on a solution.

Comment: Just a quick update: I solved my problems by using the Provider/Multiprovider. 
During the logon process I load all the Userdata und notify the listeners. 

Through the app I again use notify listeners to "sync" changes within the application.